# How to have emacs, on startup, have the environment as if having read my bashrc?

Tags: emacs, environment-variables, gnome

In my `.emacs`, I have some stuff that uses environment variables defined by my `.bashrc`.

If I first open a terminal (which automatically reads me `bashrc`), and then open emacs from there, I can get everything to work. However, if I open if from GNOME's activities, it doesn't.

Is there a way to still open emacs from GNOME's activities, but have it have the environment of by `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 4):

You should probably be defining your environment variables in your ~/.profile not your ~/.bashrc so they are just loaded once during login instead of every time you launch a shell and emacs would have access to them when launched from activities by default.

But you could set a custom shortcut to launch emacs from a login shell if that's how you want to do it: e.g, => settings -> keyboard -> create custom shortcut with command like `bash -l -c 'emacsclient -nc -a ""  &'` to launch emacs from a login shell which should read your .bashrc.

Comment: setting path in ~/.profile didn't help me :(

Comment: @Asalle on Gnome?

Comment: yeah, Gnome (+Wayland if it matters). I checked the value set in PATH with `getenv` and it was some kind of truncated path. I ended up using `exec-path-from-shell`. So now I;m wondering, where did emacs get this truncated path initially? Is it the case for all graphic apps?

Comment: @Asalle you probably need to remove ~/.bash_profile if you have one.  But yea, the order of load files and which ones are used varies.  It's annoying as hell

Comment: or maybe walyand uses .bash_profile and you don't need .profile?  IIRC the init files are different than x11

Answer (score 1):

You can use [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell), this will load all your shell variables as like you start emacs from terminal.

Or you can add them manually. e.g :

```lisp
(defun aza-latex-path ()
  (setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:"
                         (getenv "PATH")))
  (add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux"))

(defun aza-go-path ()
  (setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/go/bin:"
                         (getenv "PATH")))
  (add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/go/bin"))
```

Comment: I know. The 'correct' setup would be putting any env variables that need to be used by graphical app in `.profile`. Sadly my Debian (that use LightDM) didn't pick it up. `xsessionrc` also didn't work. So I use the approach above instead or use `exec-path-from-shell`.

Comment: yea it can be tricky to figure out where to define them.  On Gnome3 I had to ensure there was no ~/.bash_profile in order for ~/.profile to be sourced at login.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a tutorial about this](https://roamingbytes.substack.com/p/emacs-on-macos-preserving-the-correct-environment-1735d2e8cb88). exec-path-from-shell can significantly increase Emacs's startup time. I prefer the Doom Emacs approach: save the shell environment to a file, and load it when Emacs starts. My article shows how to do that.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587